# why am I getting this error shape mismatch: two or more arrays have incompatible dimensions on axis 0

Tags: python, 3d, physics

I've a hat wave given some initial conditions. For x and y between 0.5 and 1, u = 2, otherwise u = 1. x and y vary from 0 to 2.

The wave is also time dependent so i am plotting then pausing then clearing the 3d graph.

Here is my code:

```
# import the modules required

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#define the grid

X = np.linspace(0,2,21)
Y = np.linspace(0,2,21)
U = np.ones((21,21))
c = 1
dt = 0.01
dx = 0.1
dy = 0.1


#initial conditions

for i in range (21):
    if (0.5<=X[i]<=1):
        for j in range (21):
            if (0.5<=Y[j]<=1):
                U[i,j] = 2

#prop and plot

UP = np.ones((21,21))

for f in range (100):
    for i in range (21):
        for j in range (21):
            UP[i,j] = U[i,j] - ((c*dt)/(dx))*(U[i,j] - U[i-1,j]) - ((c*dt)/(dy))*(U[i,j] - U[i,j-1])             
    U = UP
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,7), dpi=100)
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
    surf = ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,U[:])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback in the question

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because `ax.plot_wireframe` uses `np.broadcast_arrays` which expects all input arrays to have the same shape. What's happening is that for each iteration of `for f in range (100):` this line `X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)` is changing the shape of `X` and `Y`. Paste these lines into your code and see for yourself.

```
print X.shape, Y.shape
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
print X.shape, Y.shape
```

Try moving `X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)` out of the loop.

```
#prop and plot

UP = np.ones((21,21))
X,Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

for f in range (100):
    for i in range (21):
        for j in range (21):
            UP[i,j] = U[i,j] - ((c*dt)/(dx))*(U[i,j] - U[i-1,j]) - ((c*dt)/(dy))*(U[i,j] - U[i,j-1])             
    U = UP
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,7), dpi=100)
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    surf = ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,U[:])
    plt.show()
```